# Opening new Form, without knowing its System.Type at the time of compile and handling ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I've got and issue while trying to prevent ObjectDisposedException after closing one of the Forms with an Windows close button.

I've got a method which is responsible for opening forms, and it works until I'm trying to open "disposed" form, so I tried using try-catch block to handle it, altho can't get a hang how to show form afterwards.

```
public void FormCheck (Form form)
    {
        bool isOpen = false;
        FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
        foreach (Form frm in fc)
        {
            if (frm.Name == form.Name)
            {
                form.Focus();
                isOpen = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isOpen == false)
        {
            try
            {
                form.Show();
            }
            catch(ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                Type formType = form.GetType();
                object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
                form.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you never pass null into the method (you could check for that as well):

```
public void FormCheck(Form form)
{
    foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (frm.Name == form.Name)
        {
            form.Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
    if (!form.IsDisposed)
    {
        form.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        ((Form)Activator.CreateInstance(form.GetType())).Show();
    }            
}
```